# How to show a message when a countdown timer reaches zero in PHP?

Tags: php, timer, countdown

I'm working on a countdown timer that's built with PHP. I'm trying to figure out how to add a message that says "EXPIRED" after the countdown timer reaches zero. Can anyone help me with adding this feature into the countdown timer? I've listed the code below.`

```
<?php

date_default_timezone_set('Australia/ACT');
include 'GIFEncoder.class.php';

$time = $_GET['time'];
$future_date = new DateTime(date('r',strtotime($time)));
$time_now = time();
$now = new DateTime(date('r', $time_now));

$frames = array();
$delays = array();

$image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');
$delay = 100; // milliseconds
$font = array(
    'size'=>73,
    'angle'=>0,
    'x-offset'=>10,
    'y-offset'=>70,
    'file'=>'Transist.ttf',
    'color'=>imagecolorallocate($image, 243, 139, 0),
    'color2'=>imagecolorallocate($image, 217, 0, 0),
);
for($i = 0; $i <= 60; $i++){
    $interval = date_diff($future_date, $now);
    if($future_date < $now){
        // Open the first source image and add the text.
        $image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');;
        $text = $interval->format('00:00:00:00');
        imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
       ob_start();
       imagegif($image);
       $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
       $delays[]=$delay;
           $loops = 1;
       ob_end_clean();
       break;
    } else {
      // Open the first source image and add the text.
      $image = imagecreatefrompng('countdown.png');;
      $text = $interval->format('%a:%H:%I:%S');
      // %a is weird in that it doesn’t give you a two digit number
      // check if it starts with a single digit 0-9
      // and prepend a 0 if it does
      if(preg_match('/^[0-9]\:/', $text)){
         $text = '0'.$text;
      }
      imagettftext ($image , $font['size'] , $font['angle'] , $font['x-offset'] , $font['y-offset'] , $font['color'] , $font['file'], $text );
      ob_start();
      imagegif($image);
      $frames[]=ob_get_contents();
      $delays[]=$delay;
          $loops = 0;
      ob_end_clean();
      } 
    $now->modify('+1 second');
}

//expire this image instantly
header( 'Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT' );
header( 'Last-Modified: ' . gmdate( 'D, d M Y H:i:s' ) . ' GMT' );
header( 'Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate' );
header( 'Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0', false );
header( 'Pragma: no-cache' );
$gif = new AnimatedGif($frames,$delays,$loops);
$gif->display();`
```

Comment: PHP is not asynchronous, this is just going to gum up connections. Think about leveraging javascript to display the countdown and php to fetch the timestamp to tell it when it expires?

Comment: Have a look at javascript setInterval function.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback Blake & RGriffiths! However, I'm using this countdown timer for an email campaign and any Javascript will get stripped out of the document once it hits an inbox, especially for Gmail.

Answer (score 0):

The `setInterval` function in javascript:

```
<script>
    setInterval(function () {
       .... do something every 1000 milliseconds ....
    }, 1000); 
</script>
```

You can get it to update your timer ... if that is what you are wanting. Change the 1000 to something slower/faster as you wish.

Comment: Like I mentioned in my last comment, I can't use javascript because it'll be stripped out of the email campaign. It has to be a PHP function. I've ran into some examples but it's not quite what I'm looking for.

Comment: But surely if you are building the email with php, once the email is sent then php is no longer involved.

Comment: Your correct! But this is the tutorial I followed to build it https://litmus.com/community/learning/27-how-to-add-a-countdown-timer-to-your-email 

I'm hoping you could tell me what function to use in order to make a message popup after the timer has reached 0.

Comment: Are you saying you want to send someone an emai and then when they open it a timer starts within the email?

Comment: Absolutely! I've already tested it and it works. However, I wanted to add another feature to it by including a function that would print or echo a message that says "EXPIRED" after the timer reaches zero.

Comment: Can you send the resultant mail? I think you are getting confused with what is going on here. I have not read the example in depth but it seems that your php is creating an image (an animated gif) which is then placed into your email. It is just a picture. php is server side and once the php has completed on the server, genreated the gif, sent the email ... no more php.

Comment: Sure! What's your email?

Comment: I mean send yourself one and post the resultant source here. But as I say, you are just embedding an image into the email. It might as well be a picture of a horse. You can forget any further php once the email has sent.

Comment: The source code includes an image tag which allows the countdown timer to render. If you have time try implementing it  but to the point, Im trying to get a message to show when the counter reaches zero

Comment: You still do not get it. The php code creates a gif (read the first line of your tutorial). The gif is then sent inside your email and is created as the email is generated. So what you are asking is if an animated gif can spark an alert when it reaches the end of its loop. The answer is no.